# Firefox SDK | Add-on Development

Tags: firefox, sdk, firefox-addon

Any firefox-sdk genius here, who can help me with this. the event is not being forked after clicking on button. I'm trying this on Firefox 45

I have this code in main.js

```
// capture toggle button  event
function startCreation(e){
  // function to call when panel is shown to user
  if (e == "show"){
    //console.log("event " + e + " was emitted");
    panel.port.emit("show");
  }
  // function to call when panel gets interacted by user input
  panel.port.on("text-entered", function (text) {
    console.log(text);
    panel.hide();
  });
}
// let's create a panel to be shown on button toggeling.
var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("./panel.html"),
  onHide: handleHide,
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("getTask.js"), self.data.url("jquery.js")],
  contentStyleFile: self.data.url("panel-style.css")
});
```

Which would port on to getTask.js kept under data, which is as follows

```
self.port.on("show", function() {
  var _create_task = document.getElementById("create_task");
  var _task_id = document.getElementById("task_id").value;
  _create_task.addEventListener('click', function() {
    _text = _task_id.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    _task_id.value=''
    self.port.emit("text-entered", _text);
  }, false);
});
```

Also, here's the html present in panel.html, which should trigger the event

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="panel-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="getTask.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="task_id" name="task_id" value="Enter something"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="create_task" name="create_task" value="Create Task"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I'm not sure, which part making trouble here. Hope I could make it clear this time. I would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], This would include everything needed to actually test the code you are running (including the HTML page with the button, etc.).  The code you have provided leaves way to many possibilities as to what is actually happening (depending on what other code you have). Your statement as to the problem: "the event is not being forked after clicking on button" is unclear as to *exactly* what is happening/not happening (no way to know if the event fires, or if you are just not seeing the `text-entered` message, etc.). We need more information in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I could sort it out my self.

There were two object referring to the same "port.emit" and "port.on" calls. I had to delete one of those and voila, it worked, but thanks everyone who couldn't care less to look in for me.

**Appreciate your time. :)**